# Including Kiss_FFT library in visual studio and Eclips

Tags: c, eclipse, visual-studio, fft, kissfft

I started with learning C a few days ago and i would like to include [KISS_FFT Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kissfft/?source=typ_redirect) in visual studio and Eclips. Please help me how i can do that.

You will find the library in this link:

Answer (score 0):

Just add the kiss_fft.c file to your build project.

If you are using real and/or multi-dimensional FFTs, you will also need to build the appropriate .c files from tools/

I do not use Visual Studio nor Eclipse, but a quick googling found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92(v=vs.90).aspx) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253861/is-there-an-equivalent-of-add-existing-file-to-project-in-eclipse)

Comment: Thank you for reply Mr. Mark . Could you explain more details please . i'm sorry  about that i didin't get it. I'd like to enter only one array.